# Why does calling setImmediate twice cause memory use to sky rocket?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to implement a recursive function in nodejs using setImmediate and for some reason the memory usage of the process is sky rocketing. I've narrowed the issue down to the fact that I'm calling "setImmediate" twice from within the function body.

You can see this happen by comparing the memory usage of:

```
var numTicks = 0;
function doRecursiveThings(){
  setImmediate(doRecursiveThings);

  if(numTicks % 777000 == 0) {
    console.log(Date.now());
  }

  numTicks += 1;
}

doRecursiveThings();
```

Versus

```
var numTicks = 0;
function doRecursiveThings(){
  setImmediate(doRecursiveThings);

  if(numTicks % 777000 == 0) {
    console.log(Date.now());
  }

  numTicks += 1;

  setImmediate(doRecursiveThings);
}

doRecursiveThings();
```

You'll notice that the memory usage in the second example grows very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

In the first each `doRecursiveThings` queues a single but in the second each queues two `doRecursiveThings`.

This results in the non convergent series of doubling: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, ... also know as the powers of 2.

It is also quite like what is called a [fork bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb).

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a problem of `context` and `scope chain`s.

I mean, every time you start a new function that way, the scope chain is extended with one more level (with all the problems due to the need of walk throughout it, that are not the focus of the question), that is the `context` itself (well, actually I think the link is reversed, for it's the scope to be assigned to the context after its creation).

In the second case, at the `N`th step, you are actually doubling the number of contexts and chains and those newly generated ones are maybe sharing the common part (it depends on the actual underlying implementation) but giving births to two new completely separated and indipendent objects.

For you have introduced recursion in you function, the number of newly generated contexts objects explodes, for you start with 1, then 2, 4, 8, and so on. At the `N`th step, you have something like `2^N` newly created objects, all of them independent from the others. That means, as an example, that local variables are created for all of them, thus even if you have only a variable, you are actually let the number of them to grow exponentially. Note that likely a few bytes are spent even if you have no local variables, for the chain has to refer to the local context (where a few things live, like the function arguments array) plus all the parents' ones, so you need to differentiate them in any case.

And your memory thanks you. :-)

Because I got out of my minds the way everything should work and I'm quite sure that I missed something, [here](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/) is a link that will help to further clarify your doubts.

Answer (score 0):

The memory in your event loop is growing exponentially, every time your function `doRecursiveThings` runs, it adds 2 more things into the event loop, chewing up all the memory in libuv. To visualize the event loop, you can imagine it like this:

```
doRecursiveThings: 1 call in event loop
doRecursiveThings: 2 calls in event loop
doRecursiveThings: 4 calls in event loop
doRecursiveThings: 8 calls in event loop
doRecursiveThings: 16 calls in event loop
doRecursiveThings: 32 calls in event loop
doRecursiveThings: 64 calls in event loop
doRecursiveThings: 128 calls in event loop
```

so by the 32rd iteration from the root call, there will be roughly 4 billion things in the event loop, using up all the memory, for instance.